# Конвертирование html в pdf

Tags: pdf, php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, помогите, как можно сделать конвертирование html страницы в формат pdf средствами php. Например, есть страница, в конце кнопка сохранить в формате pdf, после чего скачивается эта же страница в pdf формате. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если что, то в браузерах можно сохранить как pdf.
По сабжу - [тык](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111979/) и [тык](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31438/).

Comment: если что, то мне нужно именно так, как написал выше!

Comment: @kiberchainik, Не кипятись, я предложил.  
И ответ на твой вопрос дал - скачивай те классы, подключай и кликай на скачку сколько хочешь!

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Как-то столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Помог плагин mPDF 5.6. Советую использовать только его, так как в других была проблема с кодировкой. А тут в PDF просто передаешь HTML файл со стилями, и он тебе показывает так, как тебе надо. Крутая штука.

Comment: спасибо большое, а картинки он как воспринимает?